# Haskell read a Map from file

Tags: haskell

I have written a map to a file and now am trying to perform a read on it. Is that possible?  One wrench in there is that the code is written and read using ByteString and ByteString.Char8. I keep getting the following error

```
fromList *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

My code is as follows:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BSC
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type Code = Map.Map Char [Bit]

writeCode :: FilePath -> Code -> IO ()
writeCode fp tr = BS.writeFile ("code_" ++ fp)
                  (BSC.pack (show (tr :: M.Map Char [Bit])))

readCode :: FilePath -> IO Code
readCode f = do s <- BS.readFile ("code_" ++ f)
                let s' = BSC.unpack s
                return (read s' :: Code)
```

Comment: Can you given an example of the `Code` you aim to write to a file, such that the error can be *reproduced*?

Comment: `fromList [('e',[1,1,0]),('h',[1,1,1]),('l',[0]),('o',[1,0])]` is one example. When I wrote it to the file that's how it appears in the file but now I can't read it back. Sorry, Bit is a datatype with either One or Zero, represented by 1 or 0

Comment: I get *Not in scope: type constructor or class `Bit'*. :(

Comment: Has  `tr2 = read $ show $ tr :: Code` same effect?. Can you also post full code that reproduce this problem please?

Comment: @LukaRahne: this should do the same since `Code` is an alias of `Map.Map...`

Comment: @astiefel: can you please give a definition for `Bit`?

Comment: Yeah here it is sorry about that. `data Bit = One | Zero deriving (Read, Eq, Ord)

instance Show Bit where
  show One  = "1"
  show Zero = "0"`

Comment: Oh I think I may have realized the problem. When I print it, I print 0 and 1 not Zero and One so it can't read it. Do you think I can map over the 0 and 1's and change them to Zero and One?

Comment: FYI, `data Bit = One | Zero deriving (... , Ord)` is very strange, because it will conclude that `One < Zero`! You almost certainly want to rearrange those constructors.

Comment: Also, if you're going to the trouble of using `ByteString`, it really doesn't pay to go through `String` with `Show` and `Read`. You should look into one of the *serialization* libraries, such as `binary` or `cereal`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you override the default implementation of Show, but rely on the default implementation of Read, which expects "One" or "Zero", not "1" or "0".

The solution is to write your own implementation of Read (you can leave Eq and Ord as it is):

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BSC
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.Map as Map

data Bit = One | Zero deriving (Eq,Ord)

instance Show Bit where
  show One = "1"
  show Zero = "0"

instance Read Bit where
  readsPrec _ ('1':xs) = [(One, xs)]
  readsPrec _ ('0':xs) = [(Zero, xs)]
  readsPrec _ _        = []

type Code = Map.Map Char [Bit]

writeCode :: FilePath -> Code -> IO ()
writeCode fp tr = BS.writeFile ("code_" ++ fp) (BSC.pack (show tr))

readCode :: FilePath -> IO Code
readCode f = do s <- BS.readFile ("code_" ++ f)
                let s' = BSC.unpack s
                return (read s' :: Code)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I've never overridden read before so it's giving me a warning about the following pattern not matching: `_ ((GHC.Types.C# #x) : _) with #x notElem ['1', '0']`. Is there a way to just tell it to act with its normal read?

Comment: There was a case missing in the Read instance, I updated my answer.